# принудительный запуск гибернации виндовс из командной строки или какое вообще бывает?

Tags: windows

принудительный запуск гибернации виндовс из командной строки или какое вообще бывает?!

Answer (score 0):

shutdown -h отправит компьютер в гибернацию

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]